# Objective c: NSString NSData reading from file problem

Tags: objective-c

I'm using:

```
NSData *output1 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"~/centralUtilOut.tmp"];
NSString *output = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:output1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"%@", output);
[output release];
```

But nothing is in the debug window.

This is in objective C.

Note: `centralUtilOut.tmp` is a normal text file

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**The problem is in the path specification.**

It seems that the `NSData -dataWithContentsOfFile:` does not expand `~`.

It works when you use full path or expand tilde in path:

```
NSData *output1 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:
                      [@"~/centralUtilOut.tmp" stringByExpandingTildeInPath]];
NSString *output = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:output1 
                                        encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"%@", output);
[output release];
```

Comment: Then how would i get the full home dir path using ~ ?

Comment: Try with `stringByExpandingTildeInPath`, see doc http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByExpandingTildeInPath

Answer (score 2):

That tilde in the path makes me think your file path might not be getting handled properly. Take a look at NSString's `-stringByExpandingTildeInPath` method to expand the path to the full, absolute path.

For example:
`NSData *output1 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[@"~/centralUtilOut.tmp" stringByExpandingTildeInPath]];`